# rails database migration issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ok so I've done a `rake db:migrate` but I need to add another attribute. So I was thinking I'll just add it to the migration file and then `rake db:migrate` again. However I noticed that it just takes me back to the command line. If I submit my form it throws an error unknown attribute. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Check out [Rails guides on migrations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html).

Comment: Migrations must be done a certain way. You can't just edit a migration file and re-run it. You can make a mess of your data that way. Migrations roll forward or are rolled back in order. If you do a migration, then need another change, you either undo the migration and create a new one, or just do an incremental migration. This is all described in the link that @JKen13579 gave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you ran `rake db:migrate` first time, the table was created in the database because of which the migration file that you ran has a status `up` now. You can check the migration status by firing `rake db:migrate:status` command.

Now, after adding the new field to the same migration, when you run the `rake db:migrate`, your migration file would not be picked up by the rake task. Only the migrations with status `down` are executed with `rake db:migrate` command.

What you need to do here is,

### Option 1: Rollback the changes

If you don't have any important data in your migrated table and it's ok to drop the table and recreate it then you can just rollback the particular migration. `rollback` the changes from the db by running:

`rake db:rollback version = version_number`

where replace `version_number` with the prefix of your migration file. For example, if you are trying to rollback changes of file `20140125190622_create_users.rb` then run

`rake db:rollback version = 20140125190622`

After this, *add the new field* in your migration file and run `rake db:migrate`.

### Option 2: Incremental Migration

Create a new migration to add the new field in the table. Run the following command:

`rails generate migration AddFieldNameToTableName field_name:data_type`

For example: To add `username` field in `users` table

`rails generate migration AddUsernameToUsers username:string`

after this run `rake db:migrate` and the new field would be added to your table.